# What is a Trio Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property, calculation-puzzle

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Trio Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Trio Words™ | Not Trio Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| BANANA | APPLE |
| EAST | WEST |
| NORTH | SOUTH |
| UNFORTUNATELY | FORTUNATELY |
| PLAY | READ |
| PLAYING | READING |
| DOGS | DOG |
| CAT | CATS |
| DOOMSDAY | ARMAGEDDON |
| THOUSAND | HUNDRED |
| PAINTING | DRAWING |

For Trio Word™ marked star above, it's also the **Perfect Trio Word™**, please also specify what condition makes the perfection. :P

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Trio Words™,Not Trio Words™
BANANA,APPLE
EAST,WEST
NORTH,SOUTH
UNFORTUNATELY,FORTUNATELY
PLAY,READ
PLAYING,READING
DOGS,DOG
CAT,CATS
DOOMSDAY,ARMAGEDDON
THOUSAND,HUNDRED
PAINTING,DRAWING
```

Hint 1:

> https://www.calculator.net/big-number-calculator.html -> For verification

Hint 2:

> ADD = 2GB
>  ARK > BED

Comment: shouldn't play be perfect as well?

Comment: Yes, PLAY is Trio but not perfect.

Comment: Added one more example PAINTING as a Perfect Trio Word~

Comment: hey there, any hints?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Just really close to the Perfect Trio Word... in comments need a little adjustment to get it :)

Answer (score 6):

A Trio word:

> has its value divisible by 3 when decrypted with A1Z26

A Not-Trio word:

> has its value indivisible by 3 when decrypted with A1Z26

A Perfect Trio Word:

> has its value equal to 45 or 90 when decrypted with A1Z26. only from the examples, it may not be able to determine the most suitable criteria for such category. @Bananenkopp proposed a very propable case that Perfect Trio Words have their value being a Triangular Number. @Hugh also proposed a possible solution that their values are divisible by 9. Another possible case is that their values are divisible by 5/15/45.

Comment: UNSTABLE is 21+14+19+20+1+2+12+5 = 94 = not value divisible by 3. I was about to post my answer, but found that.

Comment: @Jan Ivan I have changed an example pair :P

Comment: maybe the reason for perfection is its value is a rot13(Gevnathyne ahzore)

Comment: Not close to the rot13(Gevnathyne ahzore)  :P

Answer (score 3):

Just a small expansion of OmegaKrypton answer:

A Perfect Trio Word:

> is where the number obtained by A1Z26 is divisible by 9 (it's my first answer), but as noticed in comments then play also should be perfect word while it's not, so we can add another divisor.
> For the perfect words we see their decomposition as 
> $1) 3*3*5$ 
> $2) 3*3*5$ 
> $3) 2*3*3*5$ 
> We can conclude that common prime factors are 3*3*5, so perfect word is word which A1Z26 cipher sum divisible by 3*3*5=45

Comment: not necessarily...

Comment: play = 54 but not perfect

Comment: Nice attempt, need be more perfect :P

Comment: Just one step closer to the perfection~

Comment: @Conifers I guess now should be perfect :)

Comment: Hmm, should not 5(quintet) is odd in perfect Trio? :P

Comment: ohh, makes sence:)

Comment: This seems arbitrary. Okay, how about that a perfect trio word is divisible by 3*3*(((33/3) mod 3)+3)?

Comment: Not too much complex... :P

Comment: @hdsdv cool workaround though:)

Comment: Another try, keeping in mind that play ,coded as 54=2*3*3*3 is trio but not perfect : perfect trio number is divisible by 3*3=9 but not divisible on 3*3*3=27

Comment: What example is divisible by 3*3=9 but not divisible on 3*3*3=27 ?

Comment: @Conifers play is divisible on 27 and so is not perfect, while perfect words are not divisible by 27(45,45 and 90)

Comment: @Igorsharm PLAY is truly not divisible by 27~ You could check it by the calculator in hint :P

Answer (score 1):

A Trio Word is:

> a word for which the sum of all its letters turned to A1Z26 is divisible by 3
>
>  `EAST` → `5+1+19+20` → `45`

A Perfect Trio Word is:

> a Trio Word that also has the resulting number of concatenating the letters turned to A1Z26 divisible by 3, at least three times
>
>  `EAST` → `511920` → `170640` → `56880` → `18960`
>
>  Wouldn't it be more perfect if they were only divisible by 3 exactly three times (just as `DOGS` and `PAINTING`)?

Comment: @Conifers what?